# SQL update multiple rows with same value

Tags: mysql, sql

I use this to update (add points) rows which `mgroup` is `15`

```
UPDATE ibf_members SET points = points + 500 WHERE mgroup = 15
```

What can I use to update (add points + 500) for rows which has its `id` as `5`, `7`, `10`, `11`, `16`, `25` *and also has* `mgroup` as `15`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use the `IN` clause for this, which is easier to read (and possibly more efficient?) than building a giant `OR` list.  Try something like:

```
UPDATE ibf_members
SET points = points + 500
WHERE mgroup = 15
AND id IN (5, 7, 10, 11, 16, 25);
```

Comment: There is no difference in efficiency (except for the fewer bytes in transmission of the query)

Comment: @ypercube - I'll take your word for it, I don't know the mySql query planner at all..

Comment: Link to MySQL documentation: [Primary Optimizations](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/optimizer-primary-optimizations.html). Search for *"and MySQL treats them the same — there is no need to change IN to OR for a query, or vice versa."*

Answer (score 1):

Just add another condition to your WHERE clause:

```
UPDATE ibf_members SET points = points + 500 WHERE mgroup = 15 AND id IN (5, 7, 10, 11, 16, 25)
```